# One Minecraft Skin will not load

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently created a new Minecraft skin on minecraftskins.com, and every time I load the skin in Minecraft, it is always the Alex skin. I know it is not something to do with 1.17 because I have loaded another skin in the same version and it works, but for some reason the one skin will not load.

Comment: Update: I have created another skin to see if it is something with minecraft or the skin, and it did not load so it is something with minecaft, any server I go on, the skins are not loaded. Also, every time I try to join LAN I get the error message: "io.netty.channel.abstractchannel$annotatedconnectexception"

Comment: Could you upload the skin to something like dropbox and provide the download link so I could check it out?